# iphone memory management (basic)

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Very basic question about iPhone memory management:

Say I have a viewController with several subviews also controlled by viewControllers. When I remove the top viewController and release the instance - what happens to its children? Are all the therein contained objects released as well?

When I run my app in instruments, I don't get any memory leaks. But the value for «all Allocations» goes up and up? (I assume that this value is the overall memory consumed by my app?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View controllers release their view on dealloc. Views release their subviews on dealloc. A release is not a dealloc.

What's retaining the other view controllers? If your view controller is, then your view controller should release them. Usually this'll be a property, so you can do self.subViewController = nil.

Additionally, if you have any IBOutlets (and I really hope you're using properties for these), you'll also have to set them to nil in dealloc.

Release what you own.

Comment: this lets me a little confused. When I remove a view from a superview using [self.view remove from superview], are the properties of this view removed from the memory or are they still there? Do I have to set the properties to nil before I release them?

Seems like I don't get the difference between a released object and one that's dealloc'd...

Comment: If more than one thing has retained an object, then release will not dealloc the object.  It's only when the retain count drops below one that dealloc is actually done.

Comment: @Urs Also important to note that [self.view removeFromSuperview] will decrement the reference count on the view property of your UIViewController, but it won't affect the reference count on the UIViewController itself.

Comment: The view should manage its own properties in -[UIView dealloc]. You should manage yours.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where your child *UIViewControllers* are referenced. If they are only referenced in the root view controller (retained when they are created and released on *dealloc*), then they will be released when it is deallocated.  If you have other references to those view controllers (from your app delegate perhaps?), they will only get released when those references are released.

Cocoa touch [NSObjects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) are reference counted, they are released when their [retainCount](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount) is decremented to zero.  The *retainCount* is decremented whenever [release](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/release) is called on an object.